# Delete file with slash in it with PHP

Tags: php, filenames, delete-file, slash

I made an app, and when it was tested, the tester made a file named: "Joe'sTestPage". Which amounted into: "Joes\'TestPage.htm". M problem is that the file is undeletable because of the slash in the name. I have tried using my ftp in my cpanel, but that cant delete it either.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: try delete Joes\\\'TestPage.htm

Comment: If it's a Linux box, use double backslashes: `\\`.

Comment: Are you sure it has a \ in the filename? I think it much more likely that whatever is reporting the name is escaping the ' by adding a \.

Comment: If you wanted to be a good samaritan, you could report this to cPanel; their software evidently had trouble deleting this file as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to delete it from within PHP. If necessary, double escape the backslash:

```
unlink("Joes\\'TestPage.htm");
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're escaping the backslash when you delete

Alternatively...

I assume you do not have SSH access to the server. If you did, you could let your shell auto-complete the filename. If you cannot resolve the issue, email your host/datacenter (It sounds like you're in a shared hosting environment) and have them remove the file.

Comment: if it's free and crappy then I highly doubt it's a dedicated server, which means it's a shared one :)